Malicious contract on the mainnet? works fine locally
I'm auditing smart contracts full-time, but I haven't seen this scam before. Check out (but do not interact with) this malicious "Money Game" contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xC6B742869aEf91c843B7997f272140731b5D6360
Now, let's analyse the transactions:
Tx_1: Deployer calls Start depositing 50 ETH with the following params:
question - What two things you can never eat for breakfast?
answer - lunch and Dinner
Tx_2: Victim calls Try with the correct answer - lunch and Dinner, and msg.value of 1.05 ETH. However, the victim loses his 1.05 ETH and gets nothing in return.
Tx_3: Deployer withdraws 51.05 ETH
I found this scam while browsing Etherscan and wasn't able to find an answer yet, because I deployed the same contract in Remix, replicated the transaction, and after calling Try I successfully got all 50 ETH of the contract's balance.
Can someone explain what's happening?

It is a well known scam contract. I've seen variation of the same code from at least 2018.
The first thing to question yourself is why there two functions that do almost the same??
function Start(string calldata _question, string calldata _response) public payable isAdmin{
    if(responseHash==0x0){
        responseHash = keccak256(abi.encode(_response));
        question = _question;
    }
}

function New(string calldata _question, bytes32 _responseHash) public payable isAdmin {
    question = _question;
    responseHash = _responseHash;
}

In particular New allows an "admin" to overwrite a previous stored hash.
If you look at the contract's transaction history there's no evidence New has been called within the regular transactions. Unfortunately Etherscan by default only show internal transaction that transferred some ether. In advanced mode you can see all internal transaction.
By analyzing the internal transaction trace at 0x6981998b5f9b3784fe24eff2e656ccf5e086dba58be649853406ddc74945e987.
You could see that the contract's New is called
0xecbb7d080decfe714abf70fb6d17640c812eeb69.9278a35a( )

    Money_Game.New( _question=What two things you can never eat for breakfast?, _responseHash=527A3E852C67B61AAC552B4D372026F34B48C9AFE366E76B6C6FA9D1EBB871E3 ) 


Thanks for reminding me about the Etherscan "Advanced Mode" in internal transactions! This clarifies everything.

Only when the msg.value > 1 ETH and the _response string is hashed in a specific way such that when converting to bytes it's equal to the responseHash can you get the WHOLE contract's balance as the refund:
    function Try(string memory _response) public payable
    {
        require(msg.sender == tx.origin);

        if(responseHash == keccak256(abi.encode(_response)) && msg.value > 1 ether)
        {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
    }

I wouldn't say that it's a scam --- it's a trickery.
The responseHash is set at the time of construction when Start is called by the legitimate admin:
    function Start(string calldata _question, string calldata _response) public payable isAdmin{
        if(responseHash==0x0){
            responseHash = keccak256(abi.encode(_response));
            question = _question;
        }
    }

In this case that was the encoded lunch and Dinner string.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x59dbaa0622849d827d5d561c1c0771c8423d95bc0767b9eaf7c0268a3d30fd0f


But you can see the victim has called Try with the correct values and did not get the reward. The problem is with Etherscan which by default only shows the internal transaction that transferred some ether. The malicious deployer has called the New function and set their own responseHash.
